# changing data-target in bootstrap using CSS(first preference) or javascript(secnd preference)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <style>
          @media screen and (min-width:500px)
          {
             .col-xs-4
                 {
                    text-align:center;
                 }
          }


            @media screen and (min-width:700px)
          {
             .col-xs-4
                 {
                    text-align:center;
                    width:100%;
                 }
          }



           .col-xs-4{
            text-align:center;
           }
           div .col-xs-4:hover{

           }
           .btn-primary{
            width:100%;
           }
          </style>

        </head>
        <body>

        <div class="container-fluid">
          <h1>Hello World!</h1>
          <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
          <div id="">
            <div class="col-xs-4"  style="background-color:lavender;"><button type="submit"; data-toggle="collapse"; data-target="#doctorVisit"; class="btn btn-primary">Doctor Visit</button></div>
            <div id="doctorVisit" class="collapse">
          <table class="table"; width:500px; height:300px; >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Sr. No.</th>
                <th>Visited with</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>edit</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="success">
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>john@example.com</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="danger">
                <td>Mary</td>
                <td>Moe</td>
                <td>mary@example.com</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="info">
                <td>July</td>
                <td>Dooley</td>
                <td>july@example.com</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"  style="background-color:lavender;"><button type="submit"; id="pharmacyVisitBtn" data-toggle="collapse"; data-target="#pharmacyVisit"; class="btn btn-primary">Pharmacy Visit</button></div>
            <div id="pharmacyVisit" class="collapse">
          <table class="table"; width:500px; height:300px; >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>edit</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="success">
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>john@example.com</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="danger">
                <td>Mary</td>
                <td>Moe</td>
                <td>mary@example.com</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="info">
                <td>July</td>
                <td>Dooley</td>
                <td>july@example.com</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
         <div class="col-xs-4"  style="background-color:lavender;"><button type="submit"; data-toggle="collapse"; data-target="#stockistVisit"; class="btn btn-primary">Stockist Visit</button></div>
            <div id="stockistVisit" class="collapse">
          <table class="table"; width:500px; height:300px; >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>edit</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="success">
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>john@example.com</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="danger">
                <td>Mary</td>
                <td>Moe</td>
                <td>mary@example.com</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="info">
                <td>July</td>
                <td>Dooley</td>
                <td>july@example.com</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script>
        function show()
        {
         alert ("hey");

        }
        </script>



        </body>
        </html>
```

please run the above using a server.
refer above code.

Exaplaination: i want to change 'data-target' to the div having id #stockistVisit when the the screen size is small. can i do it using CSS?

and if i can't do it using CSS, can i do it using javascript?

im using angularjs too. can it be done using that too?

Comment: your question is not clear? what i understand you having trouble on smaller screens? if yes than you can use position absolute on button's div. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cnzxc37v/

Answer (score 1):

You can't change a data attribute using media queries, but you can change it using JavaScript (jQuery example below).

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(this).width() < 500) $('target-here').data('blue', 1);
    else $('target-here').data('blue', 2);
});
```

`.width()` returns the window width in pixels.  Using some simple conditional statements, you can change the data attribute to different values depending on the current width.

Comment: @michael...can you please exaplain the parameters 'target-here' and ('blue',1)?

Comment: 'target-here' is the jQuery selector of the element who data attribute you're trying to change.  For example, if you have `<div id="changeMe"></div>`, the selector would be `$('#changeMe')`.  The `('blue', 1)` part is setting the data attribute `blue` to the value of `1`.  It's essentially setting `data-blue="1"` on the div element.